# Match 'exclamation mark' character 'not immediately preceded by a word'

Tags: php, regex

I want to delete every `!` character from a string that is **not immediately preceded by a word**. To accomplish this task, I was thinking about `preg_replace()` to perform a Regex match.

That is, I'd like the following blasphemy of a text:

```
search! query ! !key!words that! acc!ept exclamation! marks!
```

... to become:

```
search! query keywords that! accept exclamation! marks!
```

There is no need to take double+ occurrences into account, since I filter those out using `(![!]+)` - although if someone knows of a solution that takes double+ occurrences into consideration, I'd be more than glad to welcome it, since it removes the need for an extra lookup.

So far I have `(!\b)|(\s+!\s+)|(!\s+!)` which - besides being a bit whacky in my opinion - works almost perfectly, but sometimes removes spacing between words, producing the result of

```
search! querykeywords that! accept exclamation! marks!
```

---

**EDIT**

I need to take accented and/or uppercase characters into consideration when parsing the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove an `!` when

- there's no word break before it (as in `foo  !`)
- or there is a word break after it (as in `!foo`)

That gives:

```
\B!|!\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/xF7bG6/1

Comment: **Nice and clear**. For anyone wondering though, this will _not_ work seamlessly if there are subsequent occurrences of `!` characters (which is not an issue, as I previously stated in the original question). However, changing it to `\B!+|!+\b` solves the issue - or so it would seem - http://www.regexr.com/3acqi

Answer (score 0):

`([^a-z])\!+|\!+([a-z])`, with a replacement of `$1$2` should match multiple !'s that are not preceded by a letter (\W) or have a letter immediately after (\w).

If your regular expression language takes positive lookaheads/lookbehinds, then you can use `(?<=[^a-z])\!+|\!+(?=[a-z])` with no replacement string.

Comment: I'm yet to test this server-side, but according to http://www.regexr.com/3acqc, this would produce `search querykeyords that! accpt exclamation! marks!`. RegExr uses JavaScript to process regex, but aren't both PHP and JavaScript based on Perl Regex-wise?

Comment: @JánosWeisz I fixed the replace string in the original to `$1$2` and added an alternative.

Comment: The second one is very close to the goal, but instead of a space, it merges `query` and `keywords` together, producing a result identical to that in the question. I suppose there isn't a one-liner regex solution to decide between using a `space` and using nothing, right? Another issue I have with this solution - and which forgot to state in the question, correcting now - is that there can be accented and/or uppercase characters in the string.